# Creating extra buttons to upload files/create folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, file-upload, folder

I would like to add a few extra buttons to upload files and create new folders.
Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to add custom buttons in SharePoint library command bar, you can do it using SPFx ListView Command Set extensions.

Check below documentation for more information about SPFx ListView Command Set extensions:

1. [Overview of SharePoint Framework Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions)
2. [Build your first ListView Command Set extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api)

---

You can also find list view command set extension samples in GitHub repository at: [sp-dev-fx-extensions samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/) which will help you to get started with SPFx development.

Here's one sample related to your requirements to create folders: [Add Folders Command](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/react-command-addfolders)

[image]

---

**Update from comments**:

You can use the URL in below format to upload files to SharePoint document library:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/German/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={document library id}
```

For example:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/German/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={9e823d8b-6b7a-4895-ae4d-915662d2567b}
```

Where, "9e823d8b-6b7a-4895-ae4d-915662d2567b" is the GUID of document library which you can get it from library settings page:

[image]

Comment: I meant just the button web part linking to the library upload button.
No costum buttons or something like that, just a regular button linking to an existing feature.

Comment: Check updated answer. You can build URL in given format and use it in [Button web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-button-web-part-d2e37c48-11e8-45b9-8d9e-abdaa97c2a7a)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh! This is what i was looking for. Is there also an option for creating folders?

Comment: I don't think there is any shortcut URL like above for creating folders. You may need to develop custom solution for creating folders in library